# JMeter: Run 300 concurrent requests per second

Tags: jmeter

I have started 300 requests per second by providing following values:
Number of Threads : 300
Tamp-up : 0
But I am getting following results:

```
summary +     55 in    21s 
summary +    225 in  31.1s 
summary =    280 in  31.1s
```

what different configurations would be needed to start all requests in one go?

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, you have to take in account the time it takes to run the transaction itself.
I tend NOT to use synchronization, but to take measure on longer period of time, e.g. 15 minutes.
E.g., if your system is able to deliver one page in 2 seconds, you need to run AT LEAST 600 threads to deliver the throughput you want (probably more). 
Also, remember that the time of a single page increase with the load, so a single measurement is not enough, AND take care of errors: you have to define an acceptable threshold for errors (e.g. 0.01%), and stop measurement when you go above that.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you need to start all 300 requests at the same moment you need to use [Synchronizing Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Synchronizing_Timer)
2. If you need provide constant load at 300 requests per second rate - you'll need [Constant Throughput Timer](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-throughput-constant-timer)

Two above would cover the majority of use cases, however if you want more control on your load pattern look into [Throughput Shaping Timer](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/) (available through JMeter plugin)

Comment: I tried using Constant Throughput Timer but it still completing the requests in 33 seconds. Giving results like this : summary +      6 in  15.1s summary +    274 in    31s ..

Comment: Do you have enough loops? It looks like that the timer isn't able to orchestrate the load when not having enough threads to manage. Try putting `forever` in thread group or loop controller and set `duration` in thread group to be something like desired duration of your test.